Add comments to file headers
How to automatically add file paths like comment?
#!/bin/bash

pwd=scripts/test_copy-content
files=$(find $pwd -type f)

    for file in $files; do
    if [[ "$file" == *.sh ]]; then
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.go ]]; then
            First-line_comment="# *$file"
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.py ]]; then
        First-line_comment="# *$file"
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.md ]]; then
        First-line_comment="<!-- *$file -->"
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.css ]]; then
        First-line_comment="/* *$file */"
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.js ]]; then
        First-line_comment="/* *$file */"
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.html ]]; then
        First-line_comment="<!-- *$file -->"
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.ico ]]; then
        # avoid doing something
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.jpg ]]; then
        # avoid doing something
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.png ]]; then
        # avoid doing something
    elseif [[ "$file" == Makefile ]]; then
        First-line_comment="# *$file"
    elseif [[ "$file" == *.own ]]; then
        First-line_comment="<!-- *$file -->"
    elseif any other file type
        First-line_comment="# *$file"
    fi




    firstline=$(head -n 1 "$file")
    First-line_comment="# *$file"


    # Check if the first line contains the relative path
    if [[ "$firstline" != "$First-line_comment" ]]; then
        # Add the relative path to the first line of the file
        echo -e "$First-line_comment\n$(cat "$file")" > "$file"
    fi

done

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
bash: !-: event not found
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
bash: !-: event not found
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
bash: continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'


Depending on the language or encoding, a custom "first line comment" may easily break a shebang or other processing instructions.

The error messages in your question don't appear to match the code you posted. Shellcheck can help with syntax errors. Otherwise it'd help to see an actual example of you attempting to add the comment you want.

Why not simply sed -i '1i your_comment_here' yourfile? (note for shell scripts, you don't want to insert before the interpreter line, e.g. #!/bin/bash, etc..)

Btw.: I suggest to take a look at help case to make your code clearer.

It is elif [ test ]; then.

Your logic should provide for a default case to do nothing to the file.  This would simplify your checks to only files to be updated.  And definitely don't blindly alter files "of any other file type".  I'd also recommend inserting a searchable tag inside the comment along with a timestamp.

if [[ test ]]; then elif [[ test ]]; then is a syntax error. there must be a command between then and elif. it can be :;

Don't read lines with for - especially filenames.

The errors still don't match the text of the code.  
https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  
https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive  
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

You have a number of issue in your script. You should always paste your script into Shellcheck and fix all issue and then post here. It dramatically cuts down on the number of issues to addres.
Your immediate issues are:

you should really use something other than pwd as a variable name which itself is the name of a shell command to return the present-working-directory. While you can use it, it is best to avoid using shell command names as variable names.
file is another shell command name, fname works for a short descriptive variable name for filenames.
As corrected by @GordonDavidson, you can use *.ext with [[ ... ]] in bash (see: BashFAQ #31: "What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?), but take care because you cannot use *.ext in the [ ... ] test. The globbing will expand to every file in the directory matching the extension causing the test to fail. Instead use the builtin "${var##*.}" to trim the pathname from the left leaving only the extension.
"inserting" lines is better done with sed -i. If your sed doesn't support the -i (edit in place) option, then creating a temporary file will be necessary and using just about any other method is possible in that case, but if you can let sed worry about the insertion, it simplifies things.
for shell scripts or any interpreted language that has an interpreter line, e.g. #!/bin/bash you want to insert the comment as the 2nd or later line to avoid disabling the interpreter line.
the proper comparison for testing string equality is =, not ==, though bash will accept == as well.
instead of if ...; then; elif ...; then; fi a case statement make much more sense. It makes it simple to cut down on the number of cases you have by allowing you to combine extension that share a common comment syntax.
(there are likely other issues, but these were the initial ones identified)

An example that should do what you are wanting can be written as follows (note untested). Also note it uses a while read -r fname; do ... done < <(find ..) form rather than looping over the newline separated results of find using a for loop. A slightly more standard approach, that avoids some word splitting issues. If you have unusual filnames with embedded newlines -- either way will have to be modified.
The example with comments inline further explaining the logic:
#!/bin/bash

# use another name than pwd -- that is a shell command
cwd="${1:-scripts/test_copy-content}"

# loop over each filename
while read -r fname; do
  # check if file is a makefile
  if [ "${fname##/}" = "Makefile" ]; then
    ext="sh"                                # set extension to sh
  else
    ext="${fname##*.}"                      # extension from filename 
  fi
  # if no extension, get next filename
  [ "$ext" = "$fname" ] && continue
  # insert comment based on extension
  case "$ext" in
    sh | go | py )                          # shell, go, python or Makefile
        if [ -s "$fname" ]; then
          # non-empty, ins 2nd line         # note insert as 2nd line
          sed -i "2i # *$fname" "$fname"
        else
          # empty-file, create 1st line
          printf "# *%s\n" "$fname" > "$fname"
        fi
        ;;
    md | html | own )                       # markdown, html or own
        if [ -s "$fname" ]; then
          # non-empty, ins 1st line
          sed -i "1i <!-- *$fname -->" "$fname"
        else
          # empty-file, create 1st line
          printf "<!-- *%s -->\n" "$fname" > "$fname"
        fi
        ;;
    css | js )                              # css or js
        if [ -s "$fname" ]; then
          # non-empty, ins 1st line
          sed -i "1i /* *$fname */" "$fname"
        else
          # empty-file, create 1st line
          printf "/* *%s */\n" "$fname" > "$fname"
        fi
        ;;
    ico | jpg | png )                       # images
        # do nothing
        ;;
    * )                                     # all other files
        if [ -s "$fname" ]; then
          # non-empty, ins 1st line
          sed -i "1i # *$fname" "$fname"
        else
          # empty-file, create 1st line
          printf "# *%s\n" "$fname" > "$fname"
        fi
        ;;
  esac
done < <(find "$cwd" -type f -printf "%P\n")

note: sed will not insert values in an empty-file, so the [ -s "$fname" ] test is used to make sure the file exists and is non-empty. Otherwise a new first line is simply created in the empty file using redirection.
also note: the test [ "$ext" = "$fname" ] which tests for files with no extension. (there are also additional corner cases here - but those are left to you) You will need to identify any special cases you have an adjust your script accordingly.
finally: -printf "%P\n" was added as an option to find to remove the leading ./ that complicates tests related to the extension and filename.
Let me know if you have questions or problems and I'm happy to help further.

Thank you Gordon, I stand corrected on the [[...]] point. Seems infants Alzheimer's is slowly slipping in. (edited and updated accordingly)


How to automatically add file paths like comment?

Simply try to correct and refactor the code you provided currently.
#!/bin/bash

pwd=scripts/test_copy-content

files=$(find "$pwd" -type f)

for file in $files; do
    case "$file" in
        *.sh|Makefile)
            First-line_comment="# *$file"
            ;;
        *.go|*.py)
            First-line_comment="# *$file"
            ;;
        *.md|*.html)
            First-line_comment="<!-- *$file -->"
            ;;
        *.css|*.js)
            First-line_comment="/* *$file */"
            ;;
        *.ico|*.jpg|*.png)
            # Skip these file types
            continue
            ;;
        *)
            First-line_comment="# *$file"
            ;;
    esac

    firstline=$(head -n 1 "$file")

    if [[ "$firstline" != "$First-line_comment" ]]; then
        echo "$First-line_comment\n$(cat "$file")" > "$file"
    fi

done

